# How can I run make command by using specific gcc compiler?

Tags: c++, makefile

I have to run make command using specific version gcc compiler (using gcc-4.1 because after that versions will give deprecated method warnings or errors).. Now, there are several versions of gcc installed in the server. Can anybody help, how can I run it (make command) to a specific version gcc compiler (means on gcc-4.1).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do:

```
CC=gcc-4.1 make
```

That will fill the $(CC) variable of your make. Also, you can write:

```
make CC=gcc-4.1
```

Answer (score 0):

If your makefile does not reset the compiler and your rules do not have the compiler hardcoded, you can use the CC and CXX environment variables to control what compiler will be used.